# List of Mysql "Write" commands, or how to determine whether a mysql command involves a write operation

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to identify all the write commands to mysql database and perform a function every time a mysql write command is called. This could be something like filtering (blocking) some of the commands or making a web request on a new thread. As of right now, I'm planning to use the general log of mysql to determine what these write commands are, but this doesn't work for filtering (blocking) commands.

Here's a list of some "write" mysql commands i've found:

- insert
- update
- replace

Are there any other edge cases I have to worry about? For example, is there anything that could modify a select command to make it a write operation somehow? Would the following write operation eventually be re-executed as one of the above 3?

Is "set" a write command to the database, or only for variables used in the mysql session?

Comment: You want to do this filtering in your application code ? Is it PHP ?

Comment: It would be easier to modify at the mysql level I think, but if it's not possible, then yes at that level would be good. It is php/laravel

Comment: Ok. I have had written a custom code to achieve similar sort of thing, but for a different requirement - Master - Slave Load distribution. I am posting an answer soon.

Answer (score 2):

I had done a similar sort of filtering in PHP code. The context was different though; we were utilizing Master-Slave replication architecture. For directing queries to relevant servers (Read queries to Slave, and Write Queries to Master), a custom function is written to identify the **type** of query.

One noteworthy point is that, queries within a Transaction/Lock/Unlock operation, are always considered Write queries.

Also, for `Set`, only `SET AUTOCOMMIT` and `SET TRANSACTION` are Write commands.

Please find below a largely toned down version of the actual code we are using:

```
/*
* All the WRITE operation commands
*/
$write_commands = array(
    'create', 
    'alter', 
    'drop', 
    'truncate',
    'comment', 
    'rename', 
    'insert', 
    'update',
    'delete', 
    'merge', 
    'call', 
    'lock', 
    'unlock',
    'start', 
    'commit', 
    'rollback', 
    'savepoint',
    'set', 
    'replace' 
);


/*
* method to determine whether Read or Write
* @param $sql String (SQL query string)
* @return: void
*/
function determineReadOrWrite(string $sql): void {

    $dml_query = false;

    $words = str_word_count(strtolower(trim($sql)), 1);
    $first_word = isset($words[0]) ? $words[0] : '';
    $second_word = isset($words[1]) ? $words[1] : '';

    if (in_array($first_word, $this->write_commands)) {
        /* if it is not "set" then we set to master link */
        if ($first_word !== 'set'
        || ($first_word === 'set' && $second_word === 'autocommit')
        || ($first_word === 'set' && $second_word === 'transaction')
        ) {
            $dml_query = true;

            /* If we Lock tables or Begin a Transaction, we should run on Write servers only */
            /* till we Commit/Rollback or Unlock Tables */
            if(($first_word === 'start' && $second_word === 'transaction') 
            || $first_word === 'lock'){

                /* Set whether the current query is starting a Transaction / Lock etc */
                $this->wait_for_commit_rollback = true;
            }

            /* We are doing Commit/Rollback or Unlock Tables */
            if ($first_word === 'commit' 
            || $first_word === 'rollback' 
            || $first_word === 'unlock') {
                $this->wait_for_commit_rollback = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /* It's a insert/update/delete/etc query - to be run on Write Db only */
    if ($dml_query || $this->wait_for_commit_rollback) { 
        $this->setActiveConnectionToWrite(true);            

    } else {
        $this->setActiveConnectionToRead();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have asked a lot in this question, so what you can do:

1. If you want global counters for operations performed by MySQL then

   SHOW STATUS

will return all counters for your server including those for operations like

```
Com_insert 
Com_insert_select 
Com_replace
Com_replace_select
Com_select 
Com_update
```

You can just check those values whether any of such operation have been performed

2. Another way to monitor INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE etc. is to use triggers (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html). Example in documentation clearly shows where triggers do their best - serving as means for increasing local counters (variables). But still you should remember that triggers are specific for current operation/table.
3. Speaking of edge cases. Yes, they are - transactions and procedures for example. Procedure can include a lot of operations above. Thus you need check those.
4. And generally speaking it's not the best idea to monitor atomic operations like INSERT from outside of DB. You should rely on DB means on that (triggers, variables, global counters)